# Android: Create app to stream flash videos

Tags: android, flash, video, streaming, video-streaming

I am trying to create an Android App to stream live/archived videos from my church's website.

However, I ran into a problem because all of the streams are giving .flv (flash) videos and or flash players...

I have succesfully been able to load .3gp videos in a VideoView but because Android doesn't support flash natively I tried to open the videos via the WebView.

This didn't work. At least, not for the links that I am working with. However, I can open youtube.com and click on any video to play it - but I can't play any of the streams from the church website.

My question:
Is there any way for me to make this work?
I have access to 
1) rtsp stream of .f4v
2) http stream of .m3u8
3) rtmp stream of .fv4

I have spent 2 days searching the web for ideas or fixes and everything I find doesn't seem
to work with my particular case.

It seems to me that the only option is to have the church stream direct .3gp/mp4 files that I can access.

Otherwise, I have no clue how to make .f4v files work. No luck with the WebViews yet..

Do any of you have any suggestions for me?
P.S. I will also have to create an iOS app so looking for a solution that will work on
both platforms.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Forgot to note: Flash plugins seem to be deprecated with the lvl 18 API and will probably not last long. Should I try to avoid flash all together for this very reason?

Comment: Have you looked into HTML5 `<video>`s?

Comment: I have not. Can you please elaborate on that suggestion? My web dev guy told me that he uses an html5 embedded player for streaming to mobile devices. It does work when you go to the site and play off of there on android/iOS in the browser.

Comment: You basically want to put that functionality in an app, right? You can create a `WebView` widget in your app and load up the video inside it. As for a pretty "native" solution, I'm not sure.

Comment: I have done the WebView widget and loaded the site, however every time I play the video it crashes because the stream isn't supported for some reason, which baffles me because you can play from inside the browser.. Now when I load the same WebView with youtube.com and play - I get no crashes.

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question:

It seems that the android emulator cannot play flash/m3u8 files.

However, my nexus 7 does just fine with both VideoView and WebView!

Cool library I found is Vitamio that is supposed to solve the problem I had.
I didn't use it however.